# User Input Path as string

Tags: powershell

I have a problem:

I need the user to input the Path (of files) that will be used later but I get this error:

My problem is that the folder has files in it but I just need the Path of the entered folder:

Input should be:

```
C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\test\files
```

And I'd need that Path to be put in the variable $Source_UIP

My Powershell error is this:

```
Set-Location : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by             parameter >'Path'. Specified method is not supported.
At Z:\PS_Hash_Compare.ps1:14 char:4
+ cd $Source_UIP
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

This is my code:

```
$Source_UIP = Get-ChildItem (Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the source files')
cd $Source_UIP
$Hash_Src = Get-Filehash -Algorithm SHA256 (Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Item | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}
```

and this would be the final use:

```
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Hash_Src -DifferenceObject $Hash_Extr -Property hash -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Format-List
```

any Ideas?

EDIT: many thanks to @Santiago Squarzon for the help!
This is my working script. It works also without the Validation step. This is usefull if I enter a "wrong" Path with e.g. a *.txt (= File) instead of a path

```
$Date_Time = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HH_mm"

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

[ValidateScript({
if(-not (Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container))
{
    throw 'Invalid Path'
}

$true
})]
$Source_UIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the source files'

[ValidateScript({
if(-not (Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container))
{
    throw 'Invalid Path'
}

$true
})]
$Extracetd_UIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the Destination files'



#Compare

$Hash_Src = Get-ChildItem $Source_UIP -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256

$Hash_Extr = Get-Filehash -Algorithm SHA256 (Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Item | where {!$_.PsIsContainer})
$Hash_Extr = Get-ChildItem $Extracetd_UIP -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256


$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Hash_Src -DifferenceObject $Hash_Extr -Property hash -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Format-List

$Compare | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\test\Destination\Hash_Result-$Date_Time.txt"

Invoke-Item -Path "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\test\Destination\Hash_Result-$Date_Time.txt"
```

Comment: The error is likely to be because `Get-ChildItem` found more than 1 item (file / directory) on your `Read-Host` statement. You should clarify what you're trying to accomplish on your code as there is likely to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes this is the case. There are multiple files. I will update the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right approach, in my opinion, would be first to check if the user's input is valid, meaning that the path exists and the path is a folder.

For that, you can use many approaches, one I like to use is the [`ValidateScript validation attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#validatescript-validation-attribute).
One thing to note, see that I'm not using `Set-Location` but passing the path (user input) directly to `Get-ChildItem` once we confirmed that the path is a folder, it's up to you if you wish to do it this way or with `cd`.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

[ValidateScript({
    if(-not (Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container))
    {
        throw 'Invalid Path'
    }

    $true
})]
$Source_UIP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the source files'

# where {!$_.PsIsContainer} => Can be replaced with -File
$Hash_Src = Get-ChildItem $Source_UIP -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256
```

Comment: that worked! This is a good working solution, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Timmmsa happy to help!

Comment: but I don't quite get why my Method didn't work... is it because I sent the Path (Object?) directly to the variable?

Comment: @Timmmsa your code would have worked (untested) if you used something like this: `$Source_UIP = (Get-ChildItem (Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the source files') -Directory).FullName` so `cd` would be receiving only __1__ path.

Comment: this doesn't work for me
    The variable cannot be validated because the value $null is not a valid value for the Source_UIP variable.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Source_UIP = (Get-ChildItem (Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the sour ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValidateSetFailure

Comment: @Timmmsa `$Source_UIP = (Get-Item (Read-Host -Prompt 'Get path of the source files')).FullName` works for me as long as I give a valid path but again, this doesn't validate if the path is a file or a directory. By the way, [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference) is an automatic variable and you should leave it as is (at the top of your script). `$ErrorActionPreference1` or `$ErrorActionPreference2` doesn't mean anything to PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry me is stupi ^^' Isn't Path and Dir the same? Or do you mean by Path a specific file?

Comment: To $ErrorActionPreference I didn't know that. I was thinking it is a variable as mine. I'll change that rn, thanks for helping me out again :D

Comment: Ah now I get the $ErrorActionPreference. On Inquire it'll prompt me and on Stop it obviously stops... dang I'm such a newbie as I never heard of this... So I only need this once at the start of the script... right?

Comment: @Timmmsa correct, this will define how PowerShell will act when it finds non-terminating errors.